# is it possible to create a trade command on your discord bot?

Tags: discord.js

I'm just started coding my first bot in JavaScript and I wonder if it's possible to code what Im about to tell below:
So I want this command to result in the bot sending an embed related to item trading where the bot takes the items you have for the item you want to receive. For example, 5 apples for 9 wheat.
if you don't have the 5 apples, you can't trade. But if you do, the bot should take your 5 apples from your inventory and the 9 wheat goes to your inventory. It's a simple item trading command.

If stuff is unclear, feel free to ask me more details

Comment: If you can explain it, you can program it.

Comment: Yes, you can make it. But you need a database for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, that sounds entirely possible.

You would need to implement some sorta of database (SQLite, MongoDB, PostgreSQL to name a few) in order to store information on what items the user has.

You would then run a query on the database asking for the number of specific items for a user, and depending on the result of the query perform functionality accordingly (display a message saying they do not have enough, or display a message saying the trade was successful)

Comment: After the trade goes successful, as said above, how will the 5 apples be took from your inventory and then be replaced by the 9 wheat. (As i said above)

Comment: That'll depend on your database implementation. You will likely have to write some calls to update a user's values. Unfortunately I can't just give you code because it is more involved then just giving you code. I would highly recommended looking into integrating your discord bot with a database. 

If you don't feel like looking into a database, then this project will never really be possible aside from implementing something in memory. (Which means every time you restart your bot, all progress will be deleted...)

Comment: Based on your saying this is your first discord bot, and I'm assuming based on your response you have never heard of a database before, I am going to say that this project will be too hard for you, or require some serious effort into learning